# UCDetector not detecting unused method in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed UCD detector from market place in my eclipse Oxygen. And i tried to detected unused methods in particular java file by right clicking on file - selecting UCDetector -> detect unneccessary code.

It only gives warning saying 'Class XXX has 0 references'. I checked manually in that file there are 2 unused or dead methods. Its not at all showing unused methods.

below is the file i am trying to detect unused code.
[image]

There are 3 methods, which are never used. But it does not show those methods as unused.What i am missing here?

Comment: Update your post to show your code. Nobody can resolve your question as it stands.

Comment: @skomisa I have updated my query with image, showing the file i am trying to compare. Let me know if you need more info.